# Can I use http port in telnet app on heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, telnet

I want to deploy my telnet app on heroku, but they allow to use only http traffic. Can I use http port as telnet port?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.
The heroku router will only be able to handle HTTP requests (with HTTP headers and a body), not all TCP connections.

This is not something Heroku can handle at the moment.